# Is this complex query possible in MySQL or do I need PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm planning a db-driven website that matches users based on how they answer questions. I'm thinking the best approach is to run the match calculations in the SELECT query, but I have no idea how to write the query.

Let say I have a table called **user_answer** and it looks like this:

```
+--------+-------------+--------+------------------+--------+
| userid | question_id | answer | preferred_answer | weight |
+--------+-------------+--------+------------------+--------+
| 1      | 20          | 3      |                  | 0      |
| 1      | 24          | 3      | 2, 3             | 1      |
| 1      | 36          | 2      | 2                | 10     |
| 1      | 37          | 3      | 1, 2, 3          | 50     |
| 1      | 40          | 3      | 3                | 250    |
| 2      | 20          | 3      | 3                | 10     |
| 2      | 24          | 3      | 2                | 1      |
| 2      | 25          | 2      |                  | 0      |
| 2      | 26          | 2      |                  | 0      |
| 2      | 40          | 3      | 2                | 250    |
+--------+-------------+--------+------------------+--------+
```

I want to select and order by **match_percentage** - match_percentage shoud be calculated this way:

1. Given userid = 1 (**current_user**)
2. select users with matching question_id's (**match_user** userid = 2)
3. **total_weight1** = sum of **weight** of **matching question_id**'s for
   **current_user**
4. if **answer** of **match_user** is in **current_user** **preferred_answer**, **match1_weight** = **match1_weight** + **weight of current_user**
5. **total_weight2** = sum of **weight** of matching **question_id**'s for
   **match_user**
6. if **answer** of **current_user** is in **match_user** **preferred_answer**,
   **match2_weight** = **match2_weight** + **weight** of **match_user**
7. match_percentage =  sqrt((**match1_weight**/**total_weight1**) *
   (**match2_weight**/**total_weight2**))

I don't know if this is possible. I'm expecting the DB to grow to be very large, so loading them all and doing the calculations in PHP may not be the best choice - but correct me if I'm wrong.

Is it possible to make all these calculations in a query?

Comment: Storing the preferred answer as a list of values is a bad idea.  You should use a junction table.

Comment: @Gordon: whether a separate table or a VARCHAR "set" list is most appropriate, really depends on the use case. It really depends on whether individual elements of the set don't need to be individually accessed, or added or removed from the set; that is, if the database will only ever reference a "set" list as a single VARCHAR column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I believe all the specified calculations can be performed in a query.

Assuming that (userid, questionid) is UNIQUE, we start with finding userid with "matching" questions. We could do that with a query like this:

```
SELECT u.answer
     , u.preferred_answer
     , u.weight
     , m.userid           AS m_userid
     , m.question_id      AS m_question_id
     , m.answer           AS m_answer
     , m.preferred_answer AS m_preferred_answer
     , m.weight           AS m_weight
  FROM user_answer u
  JOIN user_answer m
    ON m.question_id = u.question_id
   AND m.userid <> u.userid
   AND u.userid = 1 
 ORDER
    BY m.userid
     , m.question_id
```

Once we have that working, we can work on getting the total weights and the calculations from those.

Assuming the `preferred_answer` column is VARCHAR type, and contains a comma separated list of elements, with no spaces, e.g. `'2'`, or `'2,3,5'`, you could use the MySQL `FIND_IN_SET` function to return the index position of a particular element within the list. And that will return 0 if a "match" is not found.

I believe this query meets the specification.

```
SELECT m.userid           AS m_userid
     , SUM(u.weight)      AS total_weight1
     , SUM(IF(FIND_IN_SET(m.answer,u.preferred_answer),u.weight,0)) AS match1_weight
     , SUM(m.weight)      AS total_weight2
     , SUM(IF(FIND_IN_SET(u.answer,m.preferred_answer),m.weight,0)) AS match2_weight
     , SQRT(
         ( SUM(IF(FIND_IN_SET(m.answer,u.preferred_answer),u.weight,0)) / SUM(u.weight) )
       * ( SUM(IF(FIND_IN_SET(u.answer,m.preferred_answer),m.weight,0)) / SUM(m.weight) )
       ) AS match_percentage
  FROM user_answer u
  JOIN user_answer m
    ON m.question_id = u.question_id
   AND m.userid <> u.userid
   AND u.userid = 1 
 GROUP
    BY m.userid
 ORDER
    BY match_percentage DESC
```

NOTE:

These queries are desk checked only. I didn't set up a SQL Fiddle to test.

Item 4 appears to be a total of **current_user weight**, but only including *matching* answers. If there are no *matching* answer, we're going to return 0. Same for item 6, but just inverse.)

If there are no *matching* questions between userid 1 and some other userid, then no row will be returned for the other userid.

For a large set, this could potentially crank for a while. Suitable covering indexes should improve performance.

For improved query performance, you may want to consider "caching" the result of this query into a separate table. The contents of the "cache" table would only need to be refreshed if a row in the original table was inserted, updated, deleted. And the previously calculated results might still be "good enough" for normal access.

If you stored the results, you'd want to also return `u.userid` as a column in the SELECT list and GROUP BY.